# Increasing disk size in Vagrant archlinux using resize2fs

Tags: vagrant, archlinux, partition, btrfs

I am currently running a Vagrant box with archlinux for development purposes. I wanted to go beyond the 2GB so I installed the `vagrant-disksize` plugin and after ssh'ing into the box and changing the partition size, I ran resize2fs as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/317338/how-can-i-increase-disk-size-on-a-vagrant-vm).

However, when I do that, I get the following error:

```
resize2fs: Device or resource busy while trying to open /dev/sdax
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
```

Here's what the man page says about `resize2fs`:

> If the filesystem is mounted, it can be used to expand the size of the
> mounted filesystem, assuming the kernel  and  the file system supports
> on-line resizing.

How can I use `resize2fs` with my archlinux box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tldr**: resize2fs doesn't work on btrfs

### Resolution:

After investigating the issue, I found out that the archlinux Vagrant box was set up with `btrfs` instead `ext4`. If you want to expand your disk size on Vagrant/VirtualBox and Arch Linux you will have to.

### Steps to follow

1. Increase the physical disk size by either 1. using the Vagrant `disk-resize` plugin, 2. manually dismounting and cloning the drive with `VBoxManage`, or 3. activating the Vagrant experimental feature flag (oct. 2020).
2. Resize the partition inside the OS with `{,c}fdisk` or `parted`.
3. Check the file system on your partition with `lsblk --fs`. If you happen to run on btrfs, you won't be able to use `resize2fs`. You'll have to go through
   `btrfs filesystem resize max / (the mount point)`

A few links that could be of use:

https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=000018798

https://gist.github.com/christopher-hopper/9755310

https://askubuntu.com/questions/317338/how-can-i-increase-disk-size-on-a-vagrant-vm